# Suggestion for daylight high lumen bin-pin LED bulb

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, bulb

[Here are some photos of the fixture.](https://goo.gl/photos/jHk4ybyTTJZWNys37)

I’ve been searching around for a GU24/bi-pin base daylight LED with more 1400 lumens.

[Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n:2314207011,p_n_feature_five_browse-bin:6104132011) and [HomeDepot](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Electrical-Light-Bulbs-LED-Light-Bulbs/N-5yc1vZbm79) didn’t help much. I found quite a few bi-pin ones but none of them day light with more than 1100 lumens.

Can some help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Product recommendations are not really on topic. If you can accept cool white, feit makes an [1800 lumen gu24 bulb](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Feit-Electric-100W-Equivalent-Cool-White-4100K-GU24-Base-CFL-Light-Bulb-12-Case-BPESL27TM-GU24-41K/204689690). If you search *gu24 100 watt daylight* you will find sites that have what you re looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I wasn’t looking for a particular brand. From the link I got, it’s a CFL. I was looking for a LED.

Comment: High lumen LEDs are still fairly rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most LED bulbs recommend against installing in a closed fixture like that because of concerns about heat building shorting the lamp life.

Another approach you could take is just to replace the entire fixture with an LED one. E.g. [This LED ceiling fixture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0156YCJDU) comes in 1400 and 1700 lumen varieties. You'll probably get much better light dispersion out of a fixture like that anyway because the individual diodes are all pointing in the right direction instead of a standard bulb where half of the light is shining towards the ceiling.

Comment: +1 Good job in turning buying advice into a real solution.